# What does this apache rewrite directive do?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I came across this directive in a `.htaccess` file in a laravel project

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

but I don't understand what it does.  here are the surrounding directives.

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I understand that its the last rewrite to be made and that`^` character to be the anchor for a new line, but there doesn't seem to be a pattern to match?
What does this rewrite directive do?
Does it replace the `^` (start of line) with the string `index.php`, if so does the rest of the URL get retained or does the entire URL get reset to `index.php`?

Comment: Thanks, so is the regex matching the `^` character and replacing it? Its just I never really thought of the start of a line to be a character to be matched and replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rewrite directive

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`^` means [START] (its counterpart is `$` which means [END])

Essentially, the directive is pattern-matching any URI which begins with [START].

Obviously, that's all of them.

Comment: thanks. What Im not sure about, is the fact that normally when you want to match every URL its more common to see `RewriteRule .* index.php`. Is the reason to use the `^` because it doesn't replace the main body of the string? in that case does using `^` leave the rest of the string (that would otherwise be matched by `.*`) intact so the complete URI becomes `index.php<the original url>`?

Comment: No, for that result, the directive would need to be: `RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php$1 [L]`. Try not to think of `mod_rewrite` regex as a search and replace tool. It's close to that but subtly different: it matches a pattern and then it writes a new url (which may or may not include fragments of the pattern you have just matched).